# How to determine if a connection has been established with elasticsearch + Java API?

Tags: java, eclipse, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I'm very new to elasticsearch and the Java API. How do I determine if I've established a successful connection to elasticsearch with the API? I'd normally expect a response from the server...

Code

```
Client client = new TransportClient()
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300))
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300));
```

The node name is set to Test and I'm getting the following out of Eclipse

```
Nov 18, 2014 5:29:04 PM org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService <init>
INFO: [Hannibal King] loaded [], sites []
```

I'm not seeing anything on the elasticsearch side but I'm not familiar enough to know if this is a successful connection?

Answer (score 0):

You may ping the server if you have initiated it by its java client.

You may try writing ( indexing ) something to it and check it out via its visualizer.

```
IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet", "1")
        .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                        .field("user", "kimchy")
                        .field("postDate", new Date())
                        .field("message", "trying out Elasticsearch")
                    .endObject()
                  )
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```

or you may try reading ( get operation ) something from it via java client..

```
GetResponse response = client.prepareGet("twitter", "tweet", "1")
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```